# How to draw an interval graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I tried using the code given in this post: [How to draw intervals in latex using tikz or otherwise?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469129/how-to-draw-intervals-in-latex-using-tikz-or-otherwise)

But when I tried altering the code to fit my situation, the graph became completely jumbled (circles around the interval numbers, line segment above the intervals, etc.

I am trying to make something that looks like this:
[image]

I would appreciate any help on how to do this or how I might be altering the code from the other post incorrectly.

EDIT:

Using the code suggested below as a template, I've gotten very close:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % \draw[help lines,dashed] (-1,0) grid (10,7); % helper grid OPTIONAL 
    
    \draw (-1,0)-- (10,0); %draw the horizontal axis
    \foreach \x in {0,...,9} {
        \draw (\x,0.2) -- (\x,-0.2) node[below] {\x}; % draw the ticks
    }
    
    % first line
    \draw (0,1) -- (5,1); %straight line
    \draw[fill=white] (0,1) circle (0.15); %circle filled white over the end of the line <<<<
    \draw[fill] (5,1) circle (0.15);%circle filled black
        
    % second line + two black circles
    \draw (2,2) -- (3,2);
    \draw[fill] (2,2) circle (0.15);
    \draw[fill](3,2) circle (0.15);
    
    % third line + two black circles
    \draw (4,4) -- (6,4);
    \draw[fill] (4,4) circle (0.15);
    \draw[fill](6,4) circle (0.15);
    
    % fourth line + two black circles
    \draw (5,5) -- (6,5);
    \draw[fill] (5,5) circle (0.15);
    \draw[fill](6,5) circle (0.15);
    
    % upper line+  two white circles
    \draw (7,5) -- (9,5);
    \draw[fill=white] (7,5) circle (0.15);
    \draw[fill=white](9,5) circle (0.15);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces:
[image]

As you can see, it's almost perfect. I just need the line from 4-6 and the line from 5-6 to be moved down so that they're above the line from 2-3 and below the line from 7-9.

Any suggestions on how I might do this? I can't see anywhere in the code that is obviously controlling the line heights.

Comment: Could you post your best attempt?  Or something between the code you linked to and your jumbled attempt?

Comment: Why don't you post your failing code? That way it will be much simpler to point you in the correct direction. Like it is stated now, this seems a "please do it for me" question....

Comment: Take a look at `nl-interval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This template will help you get started.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines,dashed] (-1,0) grid (10,7); % helper grid OPTIONAL 
    
    \draw (-1,0)-- (10,0); %draw the horizontal axis
    \foreach \x in {0,...,9} {
        \draw (\x,0.2) -- (\x,-0.2) node[below] {\x}; % draw the ticks
    }
    
    % first line
    \draw (0,1) -- (5,1); %straight line
    \draw[fill=white] (0,1) circle (0.15); %circle filled white over the end of the line <<<<
    \draw[fill] (5,1) circle (0.15);%circle filled black
        
    % second line + two black circles
    \draw (2,2) -- (3,2);
    \draw[fill] (2,2) circle (0.15);
    \draw[fill](3,2) circle (0.15);
    
    % upper line+  two white circles
    \draw (7,5) -- (9,5);
    \draw[fill=white] (7,5) circle (0.15);
    \draw[fill=white](9,5) circle (0.15);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```